# Kendo UI ComboBox retains value but not text on return to page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI for MVC and am experiencing strange behavior with the ComboBox when I do the following:

1. Select an item in the ComboBox.
2. Navigate away from the page.
3. Use the browser's Back button to return to the page.

Upon returning, the ComboBox is blank (or the placeholder appears if I configured that). However, when I open the ComboBox, the item I had originally selected is highlighted. Thus, it appears that the value was retained though the text was not.

Normally, data entry items retain the value they had when you left the page, so this behavior seems non-standard.

Is there any way to make sure the ComboBox retains its text when returning to the page?

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Seeing some of your code would help, but I will throw this out.  This is a bit undocumented to use the Kendo().DropDownListFor but I find it to be the best.  I have also found that it is best to go ahead and convert your list options from whatever your data looks like to IList of SelectListItem, saves a lot of grief later.  This is a partial that gets dropped in a bunch of views.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ChangeProject" }))
{   
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentProjectId)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 450px;" })
        .OptionLabel("Project...")
        .BindTo(Model.ProjectSelectList)
        .Events(events => events.Change("submitProjectForm"))
    )
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitProjectForm() {
            $('#ChangeProject').submit();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Model applied to page...

```
public class ThisViewModel
{
    public int CurrentProjectId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> ProjectSelectList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of control equal text of commboBox before sumit or go to new page:

```
$("#controlid").val($("#controlid").data("kendoComboBox").text());
```